# Custom visual picker onclick fires two click events (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, onclick

This morning I'm told a [visual picker](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/visual-picker/) doesn't work anymore. Simplified version:

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-visual-picker slds-visual-picker_medium" onclick={handleClick} style="color: white">
        <label>
            <span class="slds-visual-picker__figure"></span>
            <span class="slds-visual-picker__body">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:date_input"></lightning-icon>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
```

The picker toggles a state. But with a click on the upper (here white) part, two "handleClick" click events are fired instead of one. You can try:

```js
handleClick(event) { 
    // event.preventDefault();
    console.trace(); 
}
```

The same behaviour can be observed, when `lightning-icon` is replaced by other Lightning elements, e.g. `lightning-formatted-text`. In fact all components extending LightningElement will do.

Uncommenting `event.preventDefault()` fixes the issue. One can hardly be too generous with preventDefault()!

This is likely due to the recent update "Spring '24 Major Release" on this org.

Is there any [change in the Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_components.htm&release=248&type=5) that should have alarmed me?

Is anything wrong with the markup?

Can I assume that this is a bug and a behaviour likely to disappear soon?